# How to write switch case and serial read for this?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, switch-statement

Subject: Work with Masses ARDUINO using the Serial Library!

Determine which category will include a child, knowing his or her age: baby (0-2), child (2-12), teenager (12-18); Switch design should be used.

I need only code, the arduino scheme has nothing to put on, I think!!

Can someone show what code will look like? I think soething like this! But I can not use more then 9 cases! If I need to write 19 for age This do not print out

```
int age =0;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
 Serial.println("\nIevadi berna vecumu diapazona no 0 lidz 18 :");
  while (Serial.available()==0);
 
  int age=Serial.read()-'0';
 Serial.println();

    switch(age){
    case 0 :
    Serial.println("baby");
    break;
    case 1:
    Serial.println("child");
    break;
    case 2 : 
    Serial.println("Teenager");
    break;
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this code.
The Serial.read() read just a character (1 byte), and int is 2 byte.
switch treats case just '==' conditions, and here must you < and > operators use.

```
int age =0;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int age=0;
 Serial.println("\nIevadi berna vecumu diapazona no 0 lidz 18 :");
 while (Serial.available()==0);
  while (Serial.available()>0){
         age = Serial.parseInt();
  }

 Serial.println(age);
//switch not good. Use ifs, else if, and else. Personalize this conditions
    if(age<5){
    Serial.println("baby");
    }
    else if (age<18&&age>4){
    Serial.println("child");
    }
    else if (age>17){
    Serial.println("Teenager");
    
    }
}
```

Good luck!